# does duplicate values in index takes duplicate space

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I want to optimize storage of a big table by taking out values of columns of type varchar to external lookup table (there are many duplicated values)

the process of doing it is very technical in it's nature (creating lookup table and reference it instead of the actual value) and it sounds like it should be part of the infrastructure (sql server in this case or any RDBMS).

than I thought, it should be an option of a index - do not store duplicate values.
only a reference to the duplicated value.

can index be optimized in such a manner - not holding duplicated values, but just reference?

it should make the size of the table and index much smaller when there are many duplicated values.

Comment: Each row present in the data will have one entry in the index - no matter whether the value already exists or not

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server cannot do deduplication of column values. An index stores one row for each row of the base table. They are just sorted differently.

If you want to deduplicate you can keep a separate table that holds all possible (or actually occurring) values with a much shorter ID. You can then refer to the values by only storing their ID.

You can maintain that deduplication table in the application code or using triggers.